# How to change font size excluding headings,sub headings, TOC ,Title using VBA macro in word document

Tags: vba, ms-word

My scenario is that I want to change font size of content body excluding title,headings,sub headings,TOC using VBA macro ,simply means change the font actual content body using macro (**Normal** style applied to actual content)

Here is my VBA code:

```
Private Sub Document_Open()
   With ActiveDocument.Content.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        .Text = ""
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
        .ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .Font.Name = "Arial"
        .Replacement.Font.Name = "Calibri"
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll         
         .ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .Font.Name = "Times New Roman"
        .Replacement.Font.Name = "Calibri"
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll      
        .ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .Font.Size = 11
        .Replacement.Font.Size = 10
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll                
    End With
End Sub
```

using this code the whole document font size is changing but font name changing only actual content only using above macro.

Is it possible using VBA macro o change actual contents of document?

Can you suggest me how can I do it using VBA Macro?

Comment: ...and please show what you have up to now adding your code to your question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are sure that the style `Normal` is applied to the document and you want to change the font properties of those parts with `Normal` style, then you can specify the style in `Find` as below:

`ActiveDocument.Content.Find.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Normal")`.

Also `.Replacement.Text = ""` will remove all the matching text from your document. Make sure that you use `.Replacement.Text = "^&"`. `^&` will replace the same text as found.

```
Sub FormatNormal()
    With ActiveDocument.Content.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Normal")
        .Text = ""
        .Replacement.Text = "^&"
        .Replacement.Font.Size = 10
        .Replacement.Font.Name = "Calibri"
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Arul,Can you please describe it using my macro ,because I am not fully aware regarding macro

Comment: @A.Raut, I have edited the answer to include a sample. Change it to fit yours.

Comment: @ Arul,I have checked from my side,but code did not worked in existing and newly created word doc

Comment: What do you mean by _did not work_?. Please be specific.

Comment: Thank you Arul for solution ,its really helpful for me I have done some changes and now its worked fine..